# Open posix message queues from systemd service

Tags: c++, posix, message-queue, redhat, systemd

I am on Red Hat 9. I would create a systemd service daemon that uses the posix message queues but I am not able to open the queue since it gives me error 24 (mq_open: Too many open files).
I tried all the settigs, the only solution is to set the resource limit inside the binary throw:

```
  struct rlimit rlim;
  rlim.rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY;
  rlim.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;
  if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE, &rlim) == -1){
  perror( "QUEUE ERROR: CMSPMsgQueue Constructor: Cannot set setrlimit");
```

but for my personal requirement I can't use this solution.
I am looking for some setting that can be set in Red Hat 9.

this is the binary source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/resource.h> /* RLIM_INFINITY*/
using namespace std;
        
        typedef struct mq_attr mq_attr_t;
        
        int main() {
        /* Code Listing 3.7:
           Sending "HELLO" through a POSIX message queue
    */
         
    /* Create and open a message queue for writing */
    mqd_t mqd = mq_open ("/OpenCSF_MQ", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_WRONLY,  0600, NULL);
    
    /* Ensure the creation was successful */
    if (mqd == -1)
      {
        perror ("mq_open");
        exit (1);
      }
    
    /* Send "HELLO" as a message with priority 10, then close the queue.
       Note the size is 6 to include the null byte '\0'. */
    mq_send (mqd, "HELLO", 6, 10);
    mq_close (mqd);
```

This file is compiled with g++ -lrt -o simplemq

This is the service file for systemd:

```
[Unit]
Description= service for test mq
After=network.target
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sysinit.target
ConditionPathExists=/proc/sys/fs/mqueue
ConditionCapability=CAP_SYS_ADMIN
MessageQueueMaxMessages=3072
MessageQueueMessageSize=3000

[Service]
# Type=forking
 Type=exec
 User=root
 Group=root
 ExecStart=simplemq
 TimeoutStartSec=0
 LimitNOFILE=5000000
 LimitMSGQUEUE=4000
 CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYS_RESOURCE
[Install]

WantedBy=default.target
```

If you try to start the service , it will fail like this:

```
Nov 24 13:03:30 test-server-rhel9 systemd[1]: Starting service for test mq...
Nov 24 13:03:30 test-server-rhel9 systemd[1]: Started service for test mq.
Nov 24 13:03:30 test-server-rhel9 simplemq[2956]: mq_open: Too many open files
Nov 24 13:03:30 test-server-rhel9 systemd[1]: test.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 24 13:03:30 test-server-rhel9 systemd[1]: test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I tried to set the systemd config file too:
the /etc/systemd/system.conf and user.conf
with:
DefaultLimitNOFILE=499999
DefaultLimitMSGQUEUE=500000

of course the ulimit -n is set to 499999 but this is not applicable to the systemd service.

in /proc/sys/fs/mqueue
the following files have the values:
msg_default  msg_max  msgsize_default  msgsize_max  queues_max
user@test-server-> cat *
10
3072
8192
8192
256

the file /etc/security/limits.conf is set to:

```
* soft core unlimited
* hard msgqueue unlimited
* soft msgqueue unlimited
#* hard nofile   unlimited
#* soft nofile   unlimited
@user - nofile   499999

root hard nofile   unlimited
root soft nofile   unlimited
```

the file /etc/sysctl.conf is set to:

```
# Increase message queue

fs.mqueue.msg_max = 3072
fs.mqueue.queue_max = 350

#soft nofile 65536
soft nofile 700000
#hard nofile 65536
hard nofile 700000
#fs.mqueue.msg_size = 1280
```

I don't know what to try anymore.
Why I am forced to set the capabilities in the binary? there is no other way to set them externally?
thank you

Comment: Just to clarify: it _does_ work if you run it as a regular user under the system-wide ulimits?

Comment: So `awk '{print $1}' /proc/sys/fs/file-nr` how many open files do you have? Does `open()` anything work?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a symptom of ENFILE (Too many open files in system) instead?

Comment: I have ulimit set to unlimited. it does work as regular user and as root only if I set the capabilities with setrlimit() inside the binary.
awk '{print $1}' /proc/sys/fs/file-nr gets 5184.

Comment: I don't think that it's related to ENFILE. the return code is 24.